# Mathematica Code with Module and If statement

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica

Can I simply ask the logical flow of the below Mathematica code? What are the variables arg and abs doing? I have been searching for answers online and used ToMatlab but still cannot get the answer. Thank you.
Code:

```
PositiveCubicRoot[p_, q_, r_] := 
 Module[{po3 = p/3, a, b, det, abs, arg},
  b = ( po3^3 - po3 q/2 + r/2);
  a = (-po3^2 + q/3);
  det = a^3 + b^2;
  If[det >= 0,
   det = Power[Sqrt[det] - b, 1/3];
   -po3 - a/det + det
   ,
   (* evaluate real part, imaginary parts cancel anyway *)
   abs = Sqrt[-a^3];
   arg = ArcCos[-b/abs];
   abs = Power[abs, 1/3];
   abs = (abs - a/abs);
   arg = -po3 + abs*Cos[arg/3]
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: More info https://newbedev.com/fast-and-robust-root-of-a-cubic-polynomial-with-constraints

Comment: This looks like code (poorly) written in a procedural language then translated into Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs` and `arg` are being reused multiple times in the algorithm.

In a case where `det > 0` the steps are

```
po3 = p/3;
b = (po3^3 - po3 q/2 + r/2);
a = (-po3^2 + q/3);
abs1 = Sqrt[-a^3];
arg1 = ArcCos[-b/abs1];
abs2 = Power[abs1, 1/3];
abs3 = (abs2 - a/abs2);
arg2 = -po3 + abs3*Cos[arg1/3]
```

`abs3` can be identified as `A` in this answer: [Using trig identity to a solve cubic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909046/119821)

That is the most salient point of this answer.

Evaluating symbolically and numerically may provide some other insights.

Using demo inputs

```
{p, q, r} = {-2.52111798, -71.424692, -129.51520};
```

[image]

*Copyable version of [trig identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909046/119821) notes - NB a, b, p & q are used differently in this post*

```
Plot[x^3 - 2.52111798 x^2 - 71.424692 x - 129.51520, {x, 0, 15}]

a = 1;
b = -2.52111798;
c = -71.424692;
d = -129.51520;

p = (3 a c - b^2)/3 a^2;
q = (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)/27 a^3;

A = 2 Sqrt[-p/3]

A == abs3

-(b/3) + A Cos[1/3 ArcCos[
     -((b/3)^3 - (b/3) c/2 + d/2)/Sqrt[-(-(b^2/9) + c/3)^3]]]
```

***Edit***

There is also a solution shown here

[TRIGONOMETRIC SOLUTION TO THE CUBIC EQUATION](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326697976_TRIGONOMETRIC_SOLUTION_TO_THE_CUBIC_EQUATION), by Alvaro H. Salas

```
Clear[a, b, c]

1/3 (-a + 2 Sqrt[a^2 - 3 b] Cos[1/3 ArcCos[
        (-2 a^3 + 9 a b - 27 c)/(2 (a^2 - 3 b)^(3/2))]]) /.
 {a -> -2.52111798, b -> -71.424692, c -> -129.51520}
```

> 10.499